# Problem App Engine app to connect to MySQL in CloudSQL

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql, mysql-connector-python

I've configured SQL second gen. instance  and App Engine application (Python 2.7) in one project. I've made necessary settings according to [that page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql).

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
env_variables:
    CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: coral-heuristic-215610:us-central1:db-basic-1
    CLOUDSQL_USER: root
    CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxx     
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: coral-heuristic-215610:us-central1:db-basic-1
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest
handlers:   
- url: /main
  script: main.app
```

Now as I try to **connect from the app** (inside Cloud Shell), the error:

```
OperationalError: (2002, 'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\' (2 "No such file or directory")')
```

**Direct connection works:**

```
$ gcloud sql connect db-basic-1 --user=root
```

was successful...

```
MySQL [correction_dict]> SHOW PROCESSLIST;                                                                                                     
+--------+------+----------------------+-----------------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id     | User | Host                 | db              | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+--------+------+----------------------+-----------------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
|      9 | root | localhost            | NULL            | Sleep   |    4 |          | NULL             |
|     10 | root | localhost            | NULL            | Sleep   |    4 |          | NULL             |
| 112306 | root | 35.204.173.246:59210 | correction_dict | Query   |    0 | starting | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
| 112357 | root | localhost            | NULL            | Sleep   |    4 |          | NULL             |
| 112368 | root | localhost            | NULL            | Sleep   |    0 |          | NULL             |
+--------+------+----------------------+-----------------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
```

**I've authorized IP to connect to the Cloud SQL instance**:
[image: The IP are authorized to connect Cloud SQL instance.]

### Any hints, help?

Answer (score 1):

Google AppEngine Standard provides a unix socket at `/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]` that automatically connects you to your CloudSQL instance. All you need to do is connect to it at that address. For the MySQLDb library, that looks like this:

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        unix_socket=cloudsql_unix_socket,
        user=CLOUDSQL_USER,
        passwd=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD)
```

(If you are running AppEngine Flexible, connecting is different and can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql))